# How to get last time change for resource in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

Example table (PK date,user_id,thing_id):

```
date      |user_id|thing_id|volume|
2018-01-12|100    |142     |12
2018-02-05|100    |140     |50
2018-02-07|100    |141     |30
2018-02-22|100    |142     |90
```

In DB row created for users thing if volume changed from last time.

I need to know what volume user have for any date.

Query `SELECT DISTINCT ON (thing_id) * FROM datatable WHERE user_id = $1 AND date <= $2 ORDER BY thing_id, date DESC` works, but it's slow and if i will have millions of rows it will be a problem.

As a result I wanna get current volumes of things:

```
updated_at|user_id|thing_id|volume|
2018-02-05|100    |140     |50
2018-02-07|100    |141     |30
2018-02-22|100    |142     |90
```

when I ask user 100 data for 2018-02-23 and

```
updated_at|user_id|thing_id|volume|
2018-02-05|100    |140     |50
2018-02-07|100    |141     |30
2018-01-12|100    |142     |12
```

for 2018-02-10

What is the best way to do this in PostgreSQL? Or maybe for that task I need some time series DB?